# R: Group by one column, and return the first row that has a value greater than 0 in any of the other columns and then return all rows after this row

Tags: r

[image]

I'm new to R programming and hope someone could help me with the situation below:

I have a dataframe shown in the picture (Original Dataframe), I would like to return the first record grouped by the [ID] column that has a value >= 1 in any of the four columns (A, B, C, or D) and all the records after based off the [Date] column (the desired dataframe should look like the Output Dataframe shown in the picture). Basically, remove all the records highlighted in yellow. I would appreciate greatly if you can provide the R code to achieve this.

```
structure(list(ID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 103L, 
103L, 103L, 103L), Date = c(43338L, 43306L, 43232L, 43268L, 43183L, 
43144L, 43310L, 43246L, 43264L, 43209L), A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", 
"A", "B", "C", "D"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: data_set[order(ID, Date),]  https://www.statmethods.net/management/sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution,

```
    ID       Date A B C D
1  101 26.08.2018 0 0 0 0
2  101 25.07.2018 0 2 0 0
3  101 12.05.2018 0 0 1 0
4  101 17.06.2018 0 0 0 0
5  101 24.03.2018 0 0 0 0
6  101 13.02.2018 0 0 0 0
7  103 29.07.2018 0 0 0 0
8  103 26.05.2018 1 1 0 0
9  103 13.06.2018 0 0 0 0
10 103 19.04.2018 0 0 0 0


data$Check <- rowSums(data[3:6]) 

data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date , "%d.%m.%Y")


data <- data[order(data$ID,data$Date),]


id <- unique(data$ID)

for(i in 1:length(id)) {

    data_sample <- data[data$ID == id[i],]

    data_sample <- data_sample[ min(which(data_sample$Check>0 )):nrow(data_sample),]

    if(i==1) {

        final <- data_sample


    } else {

        final <- rbind(final,data_sample)

    }

}

final <- final[,-7]

   ID       Date A B C D
3 101 2018-05-12 0 0 1 0
4 101 2018-06-17 0 0 0 0
2 101 2018-07-25 0 2 0 0
1 101 2018-08-26 0 0 0 0
8 103 2018-05-26 1 1 0 0
9 103 2018-06-13 0 0 0 0
7 103 2018-07-29 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly the "-7" does in your last line of code? What if I have 100 rows in my dataset? Thanks~

Comment: I have created a new column which I named Check. It is nothing but the summation of very last four columns in your data set. I did it because we are checking if there exists any number greater than zero inside any of the last four column(A,B,C,D). For example, as for 0,0,0,0 situation the summation will be 0 as well. But in situation like 0,0,1,0 , then the summation will be 1. So to detect the existance any number greater than zero, summation is a proper solution. At the last step, I have just erased this additional column. So It is not about the number of the rows inside your data set.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. The `filter` condition deserves some explanation:

1. first, we sort by `ID` and `Date` and group_by `ID`
2. Then, for each ID (since we're grouped by ID) we apply the filter condition:

   1. Test, for each row, whether any of the variables are `> 0`
   2. Get the row number for all rows (in the group) where this is the case
   3. Find the lowest one (since rows are sorted by Date, this will be the earliest)
   4. Get the value of `Date` for that row.
   5. Then filter rows where `Date` is `>=` than this.

Since we're still grouping by `ID`, all these calculations will happen separately for each group:

```
df %>%
    arrange(ID, Date) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(Date >= Date[min(which(A > 0 | B > 0 | C > 0 | D > 0))])

# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Date     A     B     C     D
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1   101 43232     0     0     1     0
2   101 43268     0     0     0     0
3   101 43306     0     2     0     0
4   101 43338     0     0     0     0
5   103 43246     1     1     0     0
6   103 43264     0     0     0     0
7   103 43310     0     0     0     0
```